How to fire off multiple actions in Remix?
My use case is a command bar for a chat app.
A single command might need to call several actions.
A pseudo code for what I am doing today is something like this...
const fetcher = useFetcher();

useEffect(() => {
  const commands = [
    {
      name: "delete-every-chat",
      onSelect: () => {
        for (const chat of chats) {
          const formData = new FormData();

          fetcher.submit(formData, {
            action: getPath('/api/chat/:uid/delete', {
              uid: chat.uid,
            }),
            method: 'post',
          });
        }
      },
    },
  ];

  // ...
});

However, it appears that sharingfetcher this way leads to situations where not every POST request is completed.
Furthermore, there appears to be no way to get the response from the action.
What's the correct way to do this?

The main thing here is to understand how actions and fetchers work. An action on a single route should only run one at a time.
A better way of doing this would be to use the fetcher to submit all the data, and iterate over it in the action. Using your example and making it simple (I've only included chats for brevity):
const fetcher = useFetcher();

useEffect(() => {
  if (name === "delete-every-chat") {
    fetcher.submit({type: "deleteAll", chats}, {method: "POST"})
  }
}, [name]);

Then, inside your action you would have something like this:
export async function action({request}) {
  const data = request.formData()
  const type = data.get("type")
  const chats = data.get("chats")

  if (type="deleteAll") {
    chats.forEach((chat) => {
      //....Delete chat here.....
    }
    return {deleted: true}
  }
  
  return null
}

As another note, here I have returned deleted as true, to get the response from the action you need to use useActionData().
const actionData = useActionData()

if (actionData.deleted) {
  //Handle change
}


This is a valid workaround, but does not answer the original question.

Possibly limitation of the fetch api, when a new fetch request is made, the response is cancelled for the old one, so you won't get a response though the server will handle both. Hence the workaround
